# Should one include the -dev suffix for branches that are not stable yet?

Tags: php, git, composer-php, versioning

I have a project in which development is done on the `master` branch. At certain points we branch of onto a release branch such as `2.1.x`. On such a branch we then have a few commits finalizing the 2.1.0 release during our RC period. And after the 2.1.0 release we might backport fixes and do additional 2.1.x releases.

It's clear that the `2.1.x` branch name is correct once the 2.1.0 has happened. However, is it correct before, while there is no stable 2.1.0 release? Or should the branch be called `2.1.x-dev` and then be renamed once 2.1.0 is tagged?

Comment: You develop in master branch and ask for a good branching scheme?? Common! Stop developing in the master branch!

Comment: @hek2mgl, there's nothing at all wrong with developing in `master`. It's not magic; it's just another branch.

Comment: @Chris Sure. The problem I saw was that OP said *we*. How will you rebase effectively if all are team members are developing in the same branch? "We merge all our dev branches into the master" would be probably ok.

Comment: Who's talking about rebasing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A branch automatically has development stability only.

Consider this as a drawback or advantage depending on what you want to achieve: A software that uses a package and does not allow dev stability will not install the dependencies of that package if they are not stable - even if that package depends on something like "2.1.0@dev" explicitly.

The drawback is that you won't be able to directly install that dependency, you'd have to allow it explicitly:

- either add that dependency package directly to the software with the same version requirement, which allows dev stability.
- or use `"minimum-stability": "dev"` to allow EVERY version requirement to install dev stability (which likely will create a huge mess and break things), so
- the minimum-stability probably should come as a pair together with `"prefer-stable": true`

Now for the branch version numbers: The branch should bear the version number it is intended to have when being a stable x.y.0 version.

Without a tagged version, a requirement of `2.1.0@dev` will install the latest commit of the 2.1.x branch when using the methods above. With tagged versions, the indirect dependencies will start to be satisfiable if the minimum stability allows for it, i.e. if the main software allows for RC packages to be installed, any tagged version like 2.1.0RC3 or the final 2.1.0 will get installed.

Note that installing branches is like trying to aim at moving targets. Branch names containing versions is slightly better than using "dev-master", but still allows for a reasonable amount of conflicts. Try to use tagged versions at any time for production software - it doesn't matter whether or not the versions are alpha, beta, RC or final, the tag must point to a defined commit and fit into the scheme of semantic versioning (i.e. shouldn't introduce backwards incompatible changes as a bugfix).